# What can Nginx/reverse proxy/load balencer help reduce load on Database?

Tags: nginx, architecture, oracle10g, load-balancing

We have two commodity servers running all our 100+ applications, we are `not` a high availability kind of shop, the request and response is usually range from 1 sec to  2/3mins as there is a lot of data processing that needs to be done on each request. Now a days the load is kind of increasing on the `database` and we cannot add more servers because the load is not on the servers, but on database, we are planning to add a smart load balancer some thing like Nginx. But from the documentation from the nginx site, I get very little information.

We have tweaked the max threads on the server, max connections in a pool etc, but, that is not an effective solution as not all database requests take a lot of time/cpu, so reducing the threads/pool size is not a go.

In our case, the request can wait until the processing is completed successfully on the first arrived requests, and then can process the remaining requests later.

Can Nginx help us make the request wait if there is a lot of load on both the load balancers?  Is it smart?

Other options we thought about is to use memcache, memsql in the future, but our data is inserted by proprietary software from Oracle, so, it writes to database directly, So, that is a work in progress in parallel to see if it works for our kind of shop.

Comment: Seems like a perfect use case for job queue, proxy won't help you too much.

Comment: @Hang Did you mean JQM https://jqm.readthedocs.org/en/jqm-all-1.3.6/? Do you know which one is good ?

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, someone else may help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of approaches you can take:

1. Caching. Keep copies of results of queries around, if the queries are repetitive. Can be done in database, between database and application, in user's browser, etc..
2. Optimization. Try to make the queries faster by adding indexes, changing way they're structured, etc..
3. Queuing. Wait until previous query is available.

You want to go with 3, but the thing about queues is that if the rate of entry is faster than rate of exit what you've got is an infinite queue. No fun. Going with 1 and 2 is likely to be more helpful.

Comment: Ive worked on jms queues, i'm aware that setting the max bean count in the memory can be adjusted so, only few beans consume the messages in the queues, when you meant queue, did you mean that there is a specific queue that can help reduce the flow of messages?